# Add onkeyup function in autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm have now autocomplete. I'm trying to add onkeyup event if value is not valid. I have here two script. One of my script is getting the value from database using ajax. My other one is just create a variable for value. What I need is connect the onkeyup event to my to my current code that have onchange event of dropdown. How I can mix up this two code?

Any help will appreciate. Thanks in advanced!

Get via Ajax my current code

```
$(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete('autocomplete.php?', { mustMatch: true });
});

function changeAutoComplete (val) {
    $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'autocomplete.php?selected='+val
    });
}
```

Ajax

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015") or die("Database Error");
    $auto = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["q"]);
    $selected = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["selected"]);
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM code WHERE item LIKE '%$auto%' AND cat_code='$selected' GROUP BY id ORDER BY item" ); 

    if($sql)
    {
        $str = array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $str[] = $row['item'];
        }
        echo json_encode($str);
    }
?>
```

autocomplete with onkeyup event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "iran", "Scheme"];
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete(data, { mustMatch: true });
});
$('input#autocomplete').result(function(event, data, formatted) {
    $("#result").html(!data ? "No match found!" : "Selected: " + formatted);
}).keyup(function() {
    $(this).search();
    $(this).css("background-color", "#D6D6FF");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do that in autocomplete callback function:

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).on("autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
 //bind keyup event here
});
```